# How to do versioning in WCF services

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I am using WCF services for the Mobile and Web platform and I want to apply the versions to them included Database version as well.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(CommonFaultContract))]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/login/{uname},{password},{uuid},{deviceName},{deviceOS}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    UserDataContract login(string uname, string password, string uuid, string deviceName, string deviceOS);
```

using the above code to call the operation contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links may help you-
[msdn data contract versioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832(v=vs.110).aspx)
[wcf handle versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807188/wcf-handle-versioning/8808893)